# Aforge Image Capture Issue

Tags: c#, windows-11, aforge

I create a Image capture program using Aforge library. this is a very basic program. when click of a button web camera activated and show image in to Picture box in c# windows application. it developed on .net 4.8. my program works on Windows 10 operating system but i can't run this on windows 11 OS. when click Enable Camera Button on win 11, it does not show anything to Pic Box.

```
`using System;
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

namespace CameraProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection filterinfocollecton;
        private VideoCaptureDevice videocapturedevice;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            filterinfocollecton = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            if (filterinfocollecton.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No web camera found.");
                return;
            }

            videocapturedevice = new VideoCaptureDevice(filterinfocollecton[0].MonikerString);
            foreach (FilterInfo filterInfo in filterinfocollecton)
            {
                cmbCamera.Items.Add(filterInfo.Name);
            }
            videocapturedevice = new VideoCaptureDevice();
            cmbCamera.SelectedIndex = 0;

         }
         
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            videocapturedevice = new        VideoCaptureDevice(filterinfocollecton[cmbCamera.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            videocapturedevice.NewFrame += Videocapturedevice_NewFrame;
            videocapturedevice.Start();
        }

        private void Videocapturedevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            picBox.Image = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videocapturedevice != null && videocapturedevice.IsRunning)
            {
                videocapturedevice.SignalToStop();
                videocapturedevice.WaitForStop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```